# Docker Networking with two interfaces

Tags: docker, networking

I am trying to setup my docker server which has two network interfaces eth0 going to my lan and eth1 going to a internal network for my vpn tunnel. And now all my containers are available through both interfaces. But I want to decide which containers are available through each interface.

I'm using docker-compose to start my containers and I have tried to create some docker networks and assign those, but I couldn't solve it that way. I also found something about macvlan networks but that seemed a bit to much for me. So I am wondering if there is another way or did I maybe misconfigure something? Or is macvlan still the easiest way to fix this?(if possible this way)

Comment: You mention your docker-compose file, but you didn't include it in the question so it would be hard for anyone to point out any potential misconfiguration.

Comment: I forgot to include it, but i thought it was not very important as i was making the networks in docker en referencing them in my docker compose file. Like this: `<network_name>:
  external: true`

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more digging i found another way which is easier to setup. I totally forgot this worked but you can just specify a which interface a port needs to bind to by giving the IP address of the interface when binding the port.
Like this when using `docker run`:
`-p 192.168.1.100:8080:80/tcp`
Or like this in docker compose:

```
ports:
  - "192.168.1.100:8080:80/tcp"
```